# Application-defiend or object-defined error when setting integer value to a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, integer, ms-access-2007

**Question:**

I think the way I set the value for variable `c` based on user's `Month` parameter input is causing Application-defiend or object-defined error. Because the program works when i set `c` values like c=1. How can I fix the conditional statement?

**Goal:**

`c=11` c is the one that stores column number, in which c=1 means column A, 11 is for column K. I would like to set the value of c based on user's 'MONTH' parameter input on "BeginDate" = `8/1/2017`

- ex) if 1 (Jan) c = 4
  8 (August)  c = 11

**Problem:**

```
Dim c As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim ret(1 To num) As Integer

For num = 1 To num
    ret(num) = Month(num) + 3
Next
c = ret(num)
```

gives me Application-defiend or object-defined error on  `xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng`
**Full Code:**

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit
  Public Function pa()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim acRng As Variant
    Dim xlRow As Integer
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\J\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Photronics")
    
    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)

    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("15_Photronic-Allen")
    
    qry.Parameters("BeginDate").Value = [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate]
    qry.Parameters("EndDate").Value = [Forms]![Run]![textendorderdate]
    
    Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim ret(1 To 15) As Integer

    For num = 1 To num
        ret(num) = Month(num) + 3
    Next
    c = ret(num)    
    xlRow = xlRow + 2
     
     Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each acRng In rst.Fields
            xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng
            c = c + 1
        Next acRng
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        c = 1
        rst.MoveNext
        If xlRow > 25 Then GoTo rq_Exit
    Loop
 
   
rq_Exit:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
End Function
```

Comment: You never assign a number to `num` before using it as the ending point of the for loop. so it is looping 1 to 0

Comment: @ScottCraner Ahh I see. Thank you for pointing it out. Would you, by any chance, advise me how i can fix it more in detail?

Comment: `For num = 1 To 15`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just changed it and still gives me the Application-defiend or object-defined error on the same line. @ScottCraner

Comment: Your two codes do not match, you need to use the `Dim ret(1 To 15) As Integer`

Comment: I'm sorry for not following you. How do you think I can use the Dim ret(1 To 15) As Integer? I thought I already do so, by suing ret(num) = Month(num) + 3?

Comment: it is that way in your second block of code

Comment: Also `c = ret(num) `  is outside the loop. so it will refer to a space that does not exist in the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes I see that, thanks to your advice!

Comment: @ScottCraner 
    For num = 1 To 15
        c = Month(num) + 3
        Next does work! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for being patient with me. would you by any chance leave a reply that way i can green check it for you?